# Head won't rotate with body

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a script where I change the player direction base on the x-position on the x axis. But i want to do something so that the character can look up and down based on the y-position on the mouse. I tried to implement it, but it doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why.

Here is my script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController characterController;


    private float xaxis = 0.0f;
    private float yaxis = 0.0f;
    public float horizontalMovementSpeed = 2f;
    public float verticalMovementSpeed = 2f;

    public float xSensitivity = 2f;
    public float ySensitivity = 2f;

    public Transform neck;

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if(!characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * horizontalMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * verticalMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            xaxis += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSensitivity;
            yaxis += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySensitivity;
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, xaxis);

            yaxis = Mathf.Clamp(yaxis, -40, 85);
            neck.eulerAngles = new Vector2(yaxis, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you debug and monitor neck.eulerAngles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are making a 2D game, as your code uses Vector2s.

You can change your implementation to use the transform.LookAt method, and pass through the mouse position.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html